# How to use Redstone dust in Minecraft PE?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have Minecraft Pocket Edition and I have collected a lot of redstone dust. For some reason, I couldn't use it for things such as iron doors. Why?

Answer (score 7):

Redstone circuits haven't been added to pocket edition yet. Currently, the only uses of redstone are certain crafting recipes such as powered rails.

Answer (score 1):

Pe 0.8.1 or 0.8.0 has redstone dust as a collectable item but is only use for compasses clocks and powered rails

Answer (score 1):

It's really bad that redstone circuits haven't been added yet, so all you can do is make compasses, clocks and rails. Let's hope for those iron doors soon! :)